# How to make a TFrame (and everything on it) partially transparent?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, transparency, delphi-xe

I have an object consisting of a `TFrame`, on it a `TPanel` and on that a `TImage`. A bitmap is assigned to the `TImage` containing a piano roll. This frame-object is put on a `TImage`, containing an image that contains a grid. See the image for an example.

[image]

Question: Is it possible to make the frame partially transparent, so that the background image containing the grid (on the main form) is vaguely visible? Ideally the amount of transparency can be set by the user. The bitmap is 32 bit deep but experimenting with the alpha channel did not help. The panel is not strictly necessary. It is used to quickly have a border around the object. I could draw that on the image.

**Update 1** A small code example is added. The main unit draws a background with vertical lines. The second unit contains a TFrame and a TImage upon it that draws a horizontal line. What I would like to see is that the vertical lines partially shine thru the TFrame Image.

**Update 2** What I did not specify in my original question: the TFrame is part of a much bigger application and behaves independently. It would help if the transparency issue could be handled by the TFrame itself.

```
///////////////// Main unit, on mouse click draw lines and plot TFrame
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls,
  Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var background: TBitmap;
    f: TFrame2;
    i, c: Int32;
begin
   background := TBitmap.Create;
   background.Height := Image1.Height;
   background.Width  := Image1.Width;
   background.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;

   for i := 0 to 10 do
   begin
      c := i * background.Width div 10;
      background.Canvas.MoveTo (c, 0);
      background.Canvas.LineTo (c, background.Height);
   end;
   Image1.Picture.Assign (background);
   Application.ProcessMessages;

   f := TFrame2.Create (Self);
   f.Parent := Self;
   f.Top    := 10;
   f.Left   := 10;
   f.plot;
end;

end.

///////////////////Unit containing the TFrame
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, 
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    Image1: TImage;

    procedure plot;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrame2.plot;
var bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
   bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
   bitmap.Height := Image1.Height;
   bitmap.Width  := Image1.Width;
   bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
   bitmap.Canvas.MoveTo (0, bitmap.Height div 2);
   bitmap.Canvas.LineTo (bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height div 2);
   Image1.Picture.Assign (bitmap);
end;

end.
```

**Update 3** I had hoped for that there would be some message or API call that would result in a solution that the control could make itself partially transparent, like the WMEraseBkGnd message does for complete transparency. In their solutions both Sertac and NGLN both point at *simulating transparency* with the AlphaBlend function. This function merges two bitmaps and thus requires a knowledge of the background image. Now my TFrame has an extra property: `BackGround: TImage` that is assigned by the parent control. That gives the desired result (it's sooo professional to see it working :-)

RRUZ points to the Graphics32 library. What I've seen it produces fantastic results, for me the learning curve is too steep.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Which you are looking for is generally resolved using layers, try using the [Graphics32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphics32/) library which supports layers.

Comment: @RRUZ, I have tried several times to understand Graphics32, but it's simply too difficult for me. I hoped there would be a solution understandable for me :-)

Comment: @Sertac, There are two Tbitmaps and two Timages. One TImage/TBitmap is on a frame so I can move this combination around.

Comment: Post some code, it may be easier to get a good answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another solution that copies the background image to the top image and `AlphaBlend`s the bitmap over it while preserving opacity of black dots:

unit1:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Unit2, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Clip_View1: TClip_View;
    TrackBar1: TTrackBar;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrackBar1.Min := 0;
  TrackBar1.Max := 255;
  TrackBar1.Position := 255;
end;

procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(TrackBar1.Position);
  Clip_View1.Transparency := TrackBar1.Position;
end;

end.
```

unit2:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TClip_View = class(TFrame)
    Image1: TImage;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Image2: TImage;
  protected
    procedure SetTransparency(Value: Byte);
  private
    FTopBmp: TBitmap;
    FTransparency: Byte;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Transparency: Byte read FTransparency write SetTransparency;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TClip_View }

constructor TClip_View.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Image1.Left := 0;
  Image1.Top := 0;
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '..\..\back.bmp');
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Image1.Width := Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Width;
  Image1.Height := Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Height;

  FTopBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  FTopBmp.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '..\..\top.bmp');
  FTopBmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Image2.SetBounds(1, 1, FTopBmp.Width, FTopBmp.Height);
  Panel1.SetBounds(20, 20, Image2.Width + 2, Image2.Height + 2);
  Image2.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize(Image2.Width, Image2.Height);
  Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FTopBmp);
end;

destructor TClip_View.Destroy;
begin
  FTopBmp.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TClip_View.SetTransparency(Value: Byte);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  R: TRect;
  X, Y: Integer;
  Pixel: PRGBQuad;
  BlendFunction: TBlendFunction;
begin
  if Value <> FTransparency then begin
    FTransparency := Value;
    R := Image2.BoundsRect;
    OffsetRect(R, Panel1.Left, + Panel1.Top);
    Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(Image2.ClientRect,
                                          Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas, R);

    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    Bmp.SetSize(FTopBmp.Width, FTopBmp.Height);
    Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Bmp.Assign(FTopBmp);
    try
      for Y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do begin
        Pixel := Bmp.ScanLine[Y];
        for X := 0 to Bmp.Width - 1 do begin
          if (Pixel.rgbBlue <> 0) and (Pixel.rgbGreen <> 0) and
              (Pixel.rgbRed <> 0) then begin
            Pixel.rgbBlue := MulDiv(Pixel.rgbBlue, Value, $FF);
            Pixel.rgbGreen := MulDiv(Pixel.rgbGreen, Value, $FF);
            Pixel.rgbRed := MulDiv(Pixel.rgbRed, Value, $FF);
            Pixel.rgbReserved := Value;
          end else                      // don't touch black pixels
            Pixel.rgbReserved := $FF;
          Inc(Pixel);
        end;
      end;

      BlendFunction.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
      BlendFunction.BlendFlags := 0;
      BlendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
      BlendFunction.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;
      AlphaBlend(Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle,
          0, 0, Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Width, Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Height,
          Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height,
          BlendFunction);
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

At launch time:
[image]

Apply transparency:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to have! But here as well with the solution of NGLN: the AlphaBlend function appears to have to know both bitmaps while in my application the TFrame is not aware of its surroundings.

Comment: @Arnold - The above code does not use the background bitmap, it copies it from the background TImage. But the same is not true for the top bitmap, you have to have an original copy of it to be able to apply different level of transparencies to AlphaBlend. I can't think any other way to achieve your requirement but to use AlphaBlend..

Comment: If the source bitmap is 32 bit, TCanvas.Draw (of that bitmap) will use AlphaBlend, so you can probably simply use Draw without having to use a BlendFunc or API calls etc., just by setting the properties of the bitmap.

Comment: @Rudy - What properties of the Bitmap I should have to set?

Comment: @Sertac - I tried to implement your suggestion but couldn't get it to work. Could you have a look at update 3?

Comment: @Arnold - First, I don't know if you've got the `OffsetRect` correct, it would depend if you've got rid of the panel, if background image is on the form or the frame, which I don't know. Second, you don't need `Frame_Image.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FTopBmp);`, it's the `AlphaBlend` that will draw on the foreground image. Third, it's not evident in your update if you've got a correctly sized bitmap for foreground image, you may need `Frame_Image.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize(FTopBmp.Width, FTopBmp.Height);` before the `CopyRect`.

Comment: @Sertac - thanks for your recommendations! It was the SetSize that worked. Your additional code to preserve the black color is very helpful for me, that is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

Hide the frame and use `Frame.PaintTo`. For example, as follows:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Unit2, JPEG, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage; //Align = alClient, Visible = False
    Frame21: TFrame2; //Visible = False
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FBlendFunc: TBlendFunction;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.Width := Frame21.Width;
    Bmp.Height := Frame21.Height;
    Frame21.PaintTo(Bmp.Canvas, 0, 0);
    Canvas.StretchDraw(ClientRect, Image1.Picture.Graphic);
    with Frame21 do
      Windows.AlphaBlend(Canvas.Handle, Left, Top, Left + Width, Top + Height,
        Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, FBlendFunc);
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBlendFunc.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
  FBlendFunc.BlendFlags := 0;
  FBlendFunc.SourceConstantAlpha := 255 div 2;
  FBlendFunc.AlphaFormat := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

The frame unit:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, Controls, Forms, JPEG, ExtCtrls;

type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    Image1: TImage;  //Align = alClient
    Panel1: TPanel;  //Align = alClient, BevelWidth = 5
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Result:

[image: Partial transparent frame]

Rewrite the above for your specific situation, ideally painting on a `TPaintBox` getting rid of the image component on the main form. But when the only significant element of the frame is the image, then I would stop using that too, and begin painting everything myself.

Comment: Impressive, I'll try this in the evening. One drawback I see is that this solution requires that the TFrame "knows" the underlying bitmap. There is no way to circumvent that?

Comment: @Arnold No, the frame doesn't have knowledge of the image on the form. Note that my frame unit has no code at all, the painting is managed in the main form unit.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `TPaintBox` instead.  In its `OnPaint` event, draw your grid first, then alpha-blend your roll image on top.  No need to use any `TImage`, `TPanel`, or `TFrame` components at all.