# how to make a transparent form inside Panel?

Tags: delphi, transparent, delphi-6

I need to create at runtime a partial transparent Form inside a Panel.

How might I be able to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use the wrong tool - forms are not normally embedded into window controls such as TPanel (though there exist exceptions). Also if memory serves only parentless windows with caption can be transparent (but I can be wrong here).

Comment: Have you seen the question from yesterday? [How to make a TFrame (and everything on it) partially transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10708488/33732)

Answer (score 2):

If your question is only related to the way to put the form in a TPanel then it's quite easy.
You only need to call **Windows.SetParent()** with the handle of the newly created form.

```
MyNewForm := TMyNewForm.Create(Self); 
Windows.SetParent(MyNewForm.Handle,MyPanel.Handle);
```

This would also work by using the TForm Property *ParentWindow*.
But it's (quite) possible that the transparency is not handled (I briefly tested with a semi opaque form and it's not drawn correctly, So if the transparency is mandatory it mights be impossible to reach your goal...)

Comment: Hi. thank you, but when a set the parent, I cannot do make it transparent. I need somethink like "break the parent style".

Actually, I need to put any TwinControl in a Panel and make this TWinControl transparent. Or could be a TwinControl in a another one TWinControl.

I dont know if I'm clear. sorry.

Thank you.